# Tell pip package to install build dependency for its own install and all install_requires installs

Tags: python, pip, cython, setup.py, pyproject.toml

I am installing a package whose dependency needs to import `numpy` inside its `setup.py`. It also needs `Cython` to correctly build this dependency. This dependency is `scikit-learn==0.21.2`. Here is the `setup.py` of my own package called `mypkgname`:

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

import Cython  # to check that Cython is indeed installed
import numpy  # to check that numpy is indeed installed

setup(
    name="mypkgname",
    version="0.1.0",
    packages=find_packages("src", exclude=["tests"]),
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    install_requires=[
        "scikit-learn==0.21.2"
    ],
)
```

To make sure that `numpy` and `Cython` are available inside mypkgname's `setup.py` when `pip` installs `mypkgname`, I set up the `pyproject.toml` like this:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=40.8.0", "Cython", "numpy>=1.11.0,<=1.22.4", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

After running `pip install -e .`, the `import numpy; import Cython` in mypkgname's `setup.py` work, but the `import Cython` inside the `scikit-learn==0.21.2` install does not:

```
    File "/home/vvvvv/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/envs/withingswpm04-38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1016, in get_subpackage
      config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
    File "/home/vvvvv/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/envs/withingswpm04-38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 958, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "sklearn/utils/setup.py", line 8, in configuration
      from Cython import Tempita
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

I don't understand why `Cython` is available for the install of my own mypkgname, but not for the `install_requires` packages of mypkgname. As if `Cython` was uninstalled(?) before installing the `install_requires` packages. But by checking the logs with `pip install -v`, it does not seem it is the case.

---

I tried installing `setuptools` and `Cython` beforehand:

```bash
pip install setuptools Cython
pip install -e .
```

and it works. Indeed, it seems that `scikit-learn==0.21.2` needs these 2 packages already installed to be properly installed. However, the scikit-learn version I am trying to install does not specify any `Cython` build requirements inside a `pyproject.toml`. Here is a link to the [`setup.py`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.21.2/setup.py) of the scikit-learn package.

If I just install `setuptools`, it still fails with the same error as in the first example (`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'`).

**Notes:**

- I am forced for some out-of-context reasons to use this specific version of scikit-learn.
- I am using Python 3.8.12, pip 23.0.1 and Ubuntu 22.04. I tried this using pyenv and virtualenv with the same results. I also tried with `pip install -v -U --no-cache-dir`.

---

How can I tell mypkgname that I need `numpy`, `Cython` and `setuptools` installed from the beginning of the `pip install` until the very end? I want the `numpy`, `Cython` and `setuptools` packages to be available in the install of `mypkgname` and in every install of the `install_requires` packages.

Since it will be a package deployed on pypi, I don't want people to have anything other than `pip` and maybe `setuptools` already installed when running `pip install mypkgname`.

Comment: "_Since it will be a package deployed on pypi_", this makes things way more complex than I thought on my first read. I do not think there is any (good) solution here but to use a Python interpreter that has *wheels* for this version of `scikit-learn` (meaning Python 3.5 to 3.7). You could also ask the `scikit-learn` maintainers to build and publish a Python 3.8 wheel for this old version of their library, no idea if they will want to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For building packages pip uses [build Isolation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/pyproject-toml/#build-isolation). I.e. it installs build dependencies into a separate virtual environment, build a package and remove the isolating venv. So build dependencies (in your case Cython and numpy) are removed along with the isolating venv.

You can disable isolation but better and more correct way is to declare your dependencies two times — as build dependencies and runtime dependencies:

```py
    install_requires=[
        "scikit-learn==0.21.2",
        "Cython",
        "numpy>=1.11.0,<=1.22.4",
    ],
```

When building your package `pip`/`setuptools` include the list of dependencies into the wheel and they will be automatically installed in the target environment along with your package.

Comment: Adding Cython and numpy in `install_requires` works. However, I still need `setuptools` pre-installed in the run venv. I could live with that. To make things clean, I would need to check that setuptools is installed inside the run virtualenv (the one that is not the build isolation venv) and fail if it not there.

Comment: I am surprised that it works... Does it work with *pip*'s build isolation enabled?

Comment: @sinoroc Why not? Build dependencies are still declared.

Comment: "Does it work with pip's build isolation enabled" -> yes, it does work with build isolation enabled.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding something. I understood that the issue is that `scikit-learn==0.21.2` does not declare any build dependency (it does not have a `pyproject.toml`), so *pip* does not know how to build it and fails. I am confused. If it were an old *pip* without build isolation I would understand, but it does not seem to be the case -- Anyway, if it works, it works. I will study build isolation again. :D

Comment: @sinoroc It could be I misunderstand the question completely but I think it's buid-time vs run-time dependencies for `mypkgname`. There're two set of dependencies and my advice was to write them 2 times. If you know a way to avoid duplication you can write an answer and win (and I'll learn). I don't know `pyproject.toml` good enough.

Comment: @sinoroc While installing scikit-learn, there is a deprecation message: "DEPRECATION: scikit-learn is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559". I think the `setup.py install` part tells us that it does not use build isolation(?)

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, *pip* lets builds (from *sdist* to *wheel*) happen in isolated environments. In each build environment, the build requirements declared in `[build-system]` are installed. Build environments are not reused. Each dependency that requires a build step will get its own ephemeral build environment.

My guess is that one dependency (direct or indirect) of your project does not declare its build requirements correctly (maybe this dependency does not even have a `pyproject.toml` file of its own at all).

Your project declares a direct dependency on `scikit-learn==0.21.2`. You also mention that you are using Python 3.8. At the following link we can see that *PyPI* does not have any built distributions (*wheels*) of `scikit-learn==0.21.2` for Python 3.8:

- https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/0.21.2/#files

There is a source distribution (*sdist*, `.tar.gz`) though. And we can see at the following link that this *sdist* does not contain any `pyproject.toml` file in order to declare its build dependencies:

- https://inspector.pypi.io/project/scikit-learn/0.21.2/packages/57/5c/133b464c8d0be7ac8c9414b6ff2ae848808a35ce03b146fc2c43777e51f9/scikit-learn-0.21.2.tar.gz/

***Possible work arounds***:

- Since  [`scikit-learn==0.21.2` has wheels for Python 3.5 to 3.7](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/0.21.2/#files), you could agree to use one of those Python interpreters.
- You could choose a version of `scikit-learn` for which *PyPI* possesses *wheels* compatible with Python 3.8.
- You could try to build your own *wheel* of `scikit-learn==0.21.2` compatible with Python 3.8.
- You could choose to disable [*pip*'s "*build isolation*" feature](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-build-isolation) with something like `python -m pip install --no-build-isolation --editable .`.

Comment: "You could try to build your own wheel of scikit-learn==0.21.2 compatible with Python 3.8." I think it would be the only semi-viable option for me. I took a shortcut inside my question, it is technically be a mirror of pypi with internal packages. So building custom wheels is an option, more complex than what @phd proposed, but possible.

Comment: Oh... if there is a private/internal package index, then yes I would definitely recommend going for building your own Python 3.8 wheel(s). This will make for much smoother user experience and it is (in my opinion) the most "technically right" thing to do.